# Navbar reloading issue

Tags: jhipster

I have a problem with my Jhipster application. In my navbar, I have a couple of "inbox" icons, and i want them to have a "unread messages" notifications on them.
The number of unread messages depend on some of the data i got in the application.

I managed to make this right, but for some reason the notifications don't appear immediately after logging in, you have to reload the page first, which kind of kills the point of the whole notification thing.

Been looking for an answer everywhere, hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question lacks so many details but I'll try anyway to answer

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is probably using some data returned from an $http or $resource service but you use it before the Promise gets resolved.